# How to revert a subversion import?

Tags: svn

I did a mistake importing in an import to some SubVersion repository, and I want to revert this import.

How can I do that?

My mistake was this: Given a folder with subfolders

```
a \
a \ a1
a \ b1
a \ c1
```

I wanted to import the folder a inside a repository folder F, so the structure in the repository be

```
F\a
```

but I imported the folders a1, b1 and c1 and the repository now is

```
F \ a1
F \ b1
F \ c1
```

I'm using Tortoise Svn, so if your instructions are in terms of that, are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
svn mkdir repo-base/a
svn mv repo-base/a1 repo-base/a/
svn mv repo-base/b1 repo-base/a/
svn mv repo-base/c1 repo-base/a/
```

where repo-base is e.g. https://svn.my.net/svn/project/trunk/

then, when you're done, check it out locally.

renaming files and moving whole directories is most reliably achieved by issuing the commands against remote paths in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first import for the repository?  Just nuke, recreate, and re-import (but do it this time).

If you were importing the tree into something other than a brand new repository, you'll have to do a bit more.

Comment: No, it is not the first import.

Comment: @hippietrail - I mean obliterate the repository and start over: rm -rf /path/to/rep; mkdir /path/to/repo; svn create /path/to/repo;

Comment: so at this point nothing will have actually been sent over to the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I see three choices.  Using a GUI like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) could make things easier.

1. Fix it where you're at

   > [Move the folders](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-copy.html)
2. Delete repository and try again

   > [Create the repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create)
3. Revert change and try again

   > See [Revert to this revision](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html)