# Is it possible to undo an import in subversion?

Tags: svn

By accident I called "svn import ..." in the wrong directory. Is there a sensible way to undo this mistake?

Googling I didn't find any useful answer, and the closest to my problem I found on stackoverflow was [importing the correct data to the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424449/how-to-revert-a-subversion-import), whereas I imported the wrong data to the correct place.

And: the repository is NOT new, so deleting it is out of question.

It would be a kind of ironic, if I couldn't undo operations in a version control system. So can someone help me? (Thanks!)

EDIT: I got my repository stored in a Berkley Database, i.e., it's in the file system. Looking at the modification date of all files/directories and at the content of the just modified files I was able to work out what to do except for one thing: does anybody know what's the file txn-current is for? I guess it's connected to the transaction handling, but what's the meaning of its content (length is 2 bytes)?

EDIT 2: Thanks for both helpful answers. I accepted Martin's answer as it should provide the proper way of doing it (as I'm under time pressure I just deleted some files as hinted in my first EDIT ignoring the content of txn-current and live fine with until now). But check out the link Wim gave in his comment!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there were no other commits since you imported your files, then you can easily delete the last revision using `svn dump`.

The following example is taken from  [this page](http://www.eiben.weite-welt.com/2008/01/delete_subversion_revision/):

- (assuming revisions 1-125 are OK, 126 is that last revision, causing the problem)
- make a backup of the repository, then dump the repository (except the last revision):

  - `> svnadmin dump -r1:125 myrepo > my.dump`
- now create a new repository and load the dump:

  - `> svnadmin create myrepo`
  - `> svnadmin load myrepo < my.dump`

Answer (score 11):

You can't undo a commit directly, the only option for this is to do an `svnadmin dump`, remove the commit from the dumpfile (either by hand using a text editor, or using [`svndumpfilter`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter), and `svnadmin load` it again.

If it's not a real problem that the data stays somewhere in the repository as an older revision, you can just `svn delete` it and commit something else instead.

Comment: Thanks, but there were some binaries in the wrong directory and I'd like to get rid of them. How could I remove the data using dump?

Comment: An older version of the SVN book has some more info on using svndumpfilter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter

Comment: Very useful link, thanks again! I'm on a different path in the moment (see the coming edit of my question), but if it doesn't work, I'll try svndumpfilter.